# Setting height property to 0 when there is no element

Tags: angularjs, css

I am trying to make a timeline for changeLogs and giving data to the timeline from AngularJS controller. My problem is that the timeline "Line" height is set to 6px. So, when there is no data in the controller, It is still showing a 6px line in the view.

What I want instead is that when there is no data, the line should have 0px height but when there is data it should have 6px height.

**Here is the excerpt from CSS**

```
.timeline {
        position: relative;
        padding: 1em 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .timeline:after {
        position: absolute;
        left: 120px;
        top: 0;
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        width: 6px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #636e72; /*Color of horizontal line*/
        z-index: 5;
    }
```

**Here is the Excerpt from the HTML**

```
<ul class="timeline">
   <li ng-repeat="log in changelogCtrl.logs | orderBy: '-dateObj'">
           <span class="direction-l">
              <span class="flag-wrapper">
                   <span class="flag">
                       <span class="time-wrapper">
                          <span class="time">
                             {{log.date}}
                          </span>
                       </span>
                  </span>
             </span>
          </span>
          <div class="direction-r move-left">
              <div class="flag-wrapper">
                  <div class="flag">
                     <strong>{{log.module}}</strong>&nbsp;<strong class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></strong>&nbsp;{{log.subModule}}
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="desc">
                 {{log.desc}}
              </div>
              </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
```

Comment: use `.timeline:not(:empty):after{/*your after code here*/}` so that the `:after` element only appears when the `.timeline` has contents.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.timeline {
        position: relative;
        padding: 1em 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .timeline:not(:empty):after {
        position: absolute;
        left: 120px;
        top: 0;
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        width: 6px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #636e72; /*Color of horizontal line*/
        z-index: 5;
    }
```

```html
 
<p class="timeline"></p> <!--with out content-->
<p class="timeline">with content</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the timeline class contains other DIV's inside of which the content is coming from AngularJS controller. Is there any way to do that, still.

Comment: Yeah by same method, but CSS has to be wrote accordingly.

Comment: @s4tr2 so content will be in `<span class="time">`.right ? so write `:after` for that `div`